# How i deploy node.js server on public domain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I've tried a lot of ways how to upload node.js server on the public domain but I've never found anything. can you help me? (Sorry for my english. I can not speak English very well.)

Comment: Do you own a public domain? do you have a host from a company or do you host it yourself at home?

Answer (score -1):

i need more info like

1. Do you use VPS or something like that  ?
2. If you use local connection , does your ISP provide static IP  ?

**Yes I Use VPS**

first check your firewall setting and allow port related to your nodejs port , i example your app use port 8000 , let tell to you firewall to allow port 8000 access tcp/udp

if you use UFW as firewall manager you can open port by **ufw allow 8000**

**No i Use Local Server**

okay you can activated NAT from your modem OR you can download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) !

**./ngrok http 8000**

to open your port

Comment: I do not use VPS. Thx for advice.

Comment: NAT is used for devices inside a LAN to make requests to outside of the LAN and get the responses routed back to the correct place. It is completely useless here.

Comment: How will downloading ngrok help? Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).

Comment: @Quentin oh my fault , i mean NAT to open port public IP on your ISP . but it use if your ISP provide static IP